# java snippets disappeared from VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code for Java development, and previously snippets like 'sysout' worked fine. Now they have stopped working and I have no idea what changed. When I type 'sysout' and/or ctrl-space, it just sits there doing nothing.

I searched the preferences for snippet-related selections in the Java-related settings, but can't find anything to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to open your `settings.json` file

and add

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
```